# How to use QWebEnginePage::OpenLinkInNewTab [Qt5.8]

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebview, qaction

When I click on link to any question in my feed on Quora using this code, the link doesn't open but it doesn't print "Hello". Could you please tell me where am I wrong? I'm pretty sure that link on quora emits the `OpenLinkInNewTab` signal. Please help, thanks.

```
class WebView : public QObject {
    void newTabRequested() {
        std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;
    }

public:
    char* home_page;
    QAction* newTabAction=new QAction();
    QWebEngineView* view=new QWebEngineView();

    WebView(char* page=(char*)"https://google.com") {
        this->home_page=page;
        this->exitFullScreen->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Escape);

        createWebView();

        this->view->settings()
            ->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows,true);

        this->newTabAction=this->view->pageAction(QWebEnginePage::OpenLinkInNewTab);

        connect(this->newTabAction,&QAction::toggled,this,&WebView::newTabRequested);
    }

    void createWebView() {
        this->view->load(QUrl(this->home_page));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `newTabRequested` is not a slot. Try

```
class WebView : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void newTabRequested(){
        std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: your method is also giving an error `undefined reference to vtable for WebView`

Comment: It's compiling for me. Is the class in a header (.h) file or in a .cpp? If the second, then you have to make a workaround and manually include the moc'ed file at the end.

Comment: I've just noticed too that the `createWebView` method is called _before_ connecting the slot. In that function you load the page. I'm not an expert in QWebEngine but, shouldn't the page be loaded _after_ connecting and setting the rest of attributes?

Comment: is it related to `QWebEngineView::createWindow(QWebEnginePage::WindowType type)` ?

Comment: As I said, not an QWEV expert, but it seems so, maybe somebody else may clarify this better